# BQ Ubuntu Phone does not find any music

Tags: ubuntu-touch, music

After the last update r21 my BQ Ubuntu Phone does not show any music, neither in music app nor in the scope. Is there a known problem with media scanner?
Problem remains even if I only put one MP3 file in my music folder on the phone.

If you have any idea how I could solve the problem please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for some of my music. The solution was simple: make sure the music tags are properly used in the mp3 files. Now the phone recognizes all my music nicely.

Comment: I have filled out all information and it is a normal 192 kb/s mp3. Is there any possibility to reset media scanner? Maybe this could help...